# Can I access locally-installed packages from a globally-installed package?

Tags: node.js, package, npm

I don't know if I've worded the question properly, so I apologize if it isn't clear from the title what I mean.

Say I have an NPM package which installs an executable. Presumably I want users to install this package with the `-g` flag so that they can run it whenever.

In this case, when I call `require()` from within the executable, it will look for packages installed globally.

But suppose this package provides generic functionality for Node projects. I might want to know which packages the current project has installed *locally*. Should I just assume:

```
path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')
```

Or is there a more "correct" way to set the NODE_PATH in this case? (Or rather than set NODE_PATH, should I just `require(absolute_path_to_file)`?)

Comment: `var resolve = require('resolve'); resolve.sync('packageName', { basedir: process.cwd() });` Nice example here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/bin/grunt

Comment: @damphat: Nice. I will totally accept that if you provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` will not only lookup the package inside `$(CWD)\node_modules` but also inside all `node_modules` of parent, grandparent, etc. So you can use `resolve` on npm to solve this problem

FILE: your_global_command.js

```
// npm install resolve
var resolve = require('resolve').sync;

// Lookup for local module at current working dir
function require_cwd(name) {
    var absolute_path = resolve(name, { basedir: process.cwd() });
    return require(absolute_path);
}

// Load local express
// this will throw an error when express is not found as local module
var express = require_cwd('express');
```

---

I also create a package to require a package at current-working-dir (instead of `__dirname` of module):
https://npmjs.org/package/require-cwd